# Will ruby on rails project start automatically when thin start

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thin

As question state.

I'm trying to start ruby on rails when machine reboot.

I feel I have successfully auto start thin.

But my ROR page is still not working.

ie:when I open localhost:3000 ,this page cant get displayed.

Is ror project start automatically when thin start?
if not,what setting do I need to do?

I'm using ubuntu, ror project under /home/usr/test

Comment: you have to start thin server in the directory `/home/usr/test`.

Comment: @SachinSingh I cant do that.I can only start use 'rails s',when I start thin use 'thin start',it gives me tons of error message,first is " You have already activated rack 1.5.2, but your Gemfile requires rack 1.4.5. Using bundle exec may solve this. (Gem::LoadError)" then follow many locations

Comment: try running thin by command `bundle exec thin start`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to tell thin that which application you want to run automatically along with thin.

```
sudo thin config -C /etc/thin/testapp.yml -c /home/usr/test  --servers 3 -e production
```

You can cross check the setting:

```
cat /etc/thin/testapp.yml
```

It should display something like:

```
--- 
pid: tmp/pids/thin.pid
address: 0.0.0.0
timeout: 30
port: 3000
log: log/thin.log
max_conns: 1024
require: []

environment: production
max_persistent_conns: 512
servers: 3
daemonize: true
chdir: /home/demo/public_html/testapp
```

Source: Rackspace's [**Knowledge Center**](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/ubuntu-thin-web-server-for-ruby)

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

you have to start thin server in the directory `/home/usr/test`.

try running thin by command `bundle exec thin start`.

Comment: thank you but my question is how to set thin to make it start ror